# Setting google files as my default app using adb

Tags: android, adb, default

I am trying to set google files as my default app using adb

In the ADB shell I am running this command
`pm set-app-links --package com.google.android.apps.nbu.file`

so it gives this exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh3pF.png)

and if I use this
`pm set-app-links --package com.google.android.apps.nbu.file always`

It gives:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfrVd.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.